# Convert lists of dataframes in dataframes

Tags: r, list, dataframe

I'm trying to create a dataframe composed by variables that are in 2 lists (but are dataframes):df and affiliation

[image]

I have tried this

```
df = data.frame(df_netflix$df)
df = data.frame(df_netflix$affiliation)
```

But when doing select the error remains: select doesn't handle lists

Comment: Instead of using `$`, try `df = data.frame(df_netflix[["df"]])` and `df = data.frame(df_netflix[["affiliation"]])`.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.